# How to update model on parent from directive with select list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that creates a select list. I need to pass in the id and value keys of the object as this is a reusable control. Why is the list not binding to its parent model when updating?

http://plnkr.co/edit/KHALRK1fBigZ2dj3bSlT?p=preview

**index.html**

```
  <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <my-dir list="characters" 
            model="model.character"
            selected-item="model.character.id"
            value-key="id" 
            text-key="name">
    </my-dir>
    <button ng-click="check()">Check</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.model = { character: { id: 2, name: 'Link' } };
  $scope.characters = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Mario' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Link' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Bowser' }
    ];

  $scope.check = function() {
    alert($scope.model.character.name);
  };
});

app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope) {
    },
    template: "<select ng-model='vm.model'>"
    + "<option value=''></option>"
    + "<option ng-repeat='item in vm.list' ng-selected='item[vm.valueKey]===vm.selectedItem' "
    + "value='item[vm.valueKey]' ng-bind='item[vm.textKey]'>"
    + "</option>"
    + "</select>",
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
      model:'=',
      list:'=',
      valueKey:'@',
      textKey:'@',
      selectedItem:'='
    }
  };
});
```

**Edit:**

This works, but then it would be a bit messy to have the blank option unless someone can give a suggestion?

```
<select ng-model="vm.model" ng-options="item as item[vm.textKey] for item in vm.list track by item[vm.valueKey]"></select>
```

**Edit 2:**

Is there a way to add into the view so that blank option actually binds to the model and has its properties as null, rather than making the actual model equal null?

So for the given example a blank value should actually look like:

```
$scope.model = { character: { id: null, name: null } };
```

and not like

```
$scope.model = { character: null };
```

which is what will happen when we select that blank value from the list. As this is a reusable control, it will be neater adding it here, rather than modifying all of the source data for every array of objects to add that null value in.

I have solved this problem using:

```
<select ng-model="vm.model" ng-change="selectChange()" ng-options="item as item[vm.textKey] for item in vm.list track by item[vm.valueKey]">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

...

```
    $scope.selectChange = function () {
        if ($scope.vm.model === null) {
            var blankItem = {};
            blankItem[$scope.vm.valueKey] = null;
            blankItem[$scope.vm.textKey] = null;
            $scope.vm.model = blankItem;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I think you should pass through a service to store the shared list

Comment: You can't use `ng-repeat` on a select if you want to bind to its model, you have to use `ng-options`

Comment: @Daniel_L Thanks. I have updated the question to include `ng-options`. What is the cleanest way to add a blank value? Any option to pass to this directive to add a blank option that I'm missing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182961/ng-options-how-to-set-first-select-always-blank for adding the blank value.

Comment: @masa Ah, thanks....I hadn't thought about adding content within the directive, but of course it would transpose it. Will add this as the answer. Thanks all!

Comment: Is there a way to not set the entire model to null as I've updated the Edit 2 to reflect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers provided by `Daniel_L` and `masa` suggest using the angular directive for `select` and then adding content to transpose a blank value at the beggining of the select list:

```
<select ng-model="vm.model" ng-options="item as item[vm.textKey] for item in vm.list track by item[vm.valueKey]">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Will correctly create all of the characters, bound to the model, and also prepend a blank option that will post null when saving your model.

if we would prefer:

```
$scope.model = { character: { id: null, name: null } };
```

instead of

```
$scope.model = { character: null };
```

to be bound to our model on the select, then we can do:

```
<select ng-model="vm.model" ng-change="selectChange()" ng-options="item as item[vm.textKey] for item in vm.list track by item[vm.valueKey]">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

...

```
    $scope.selectChange = function () {
        if ($scope.vm.model === null) {
            var blankItem = {};
            blankItem[$scope.vm.valueKey] = null;
            blankItem[$scope.vm.textKey] = null;
            $scope.vm.model = blankItem;
        }
    };
```