# select list using ng-repeat is having data but not showing up in angular js

Tags: angularjs, wysiwyg

I am using a select list in a form along with a wysiwyg angular-ui editor.
Sometime the select list works fine, but sometimes it doesn't show. I've debugged to see if it has proper values. 
Code below:

```
var app = angular.module('RESTClient', ['colorpicker.module', 'wysiwyg.module']);
<select class="required_input_mandatory inputs" ng-model="OrganizationOption" ng-change="GetUsers()">
 <option value="0">Select</option>
 <option ng-repeat="o in OrganizationModel" value="{{o.ID}}">{{o.OrganizationName}}</option>
 </select>
```

The HTML markup for the select element generates as

```
<select class="required_input_mandatory inputs ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" ng-model="OrganizationOption" ng-change="GetUsers()">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <!-- ngRepeat: o in OrganizationModel -->
    <!-- ngRepeat: o in OrganizationModel -->
    <!-- end ngRepeat: o in OrganizationModel -->
    <!-- ngRepeat: o in OrganizationModel -->
    <!-- end ngRepeat: o in OrganizationModel -->
    <!-- ngRepeat: o in OrganizationModel -->
    <!-- end ngRepeat: o in OrganizationModel -->
    <!-- ngRepeat: o in OrganizationModel -->
    <!-- end ngRepeat: o in OrganizationModel -->
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `ngOptions` directive:

```
<select 
        class="required_input_mandatory inputs" 
        ng-model="OrganizationOption" ng-change="GetUsers()" 
        ng-options="o.ID as o.OrganizationName for o in OrganizationModel">
    <option>Select</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also i need to add Select as an empty option. How do I do this ?

Comment: Not sure if my suggestion changed anything, did it? But if it did, what happen when you only add `<option>Select</option> ` to the `<select>` tag?

Comment: @AlonEitan should work. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182961/ng-options-how-to-set-first-select-always-blank

Comment: Ng-repeat is not showing any data in select options  when using `class="selectpicker"`